# Visual Studio 2017 : Broken reference to project (CS0006)

Tags: visual-studio, reference, asp.net-core-2.2

In Visual Studio 2017 I have a test project that gives me an error about not finding the reference to my ASP .NET Web Application (Core 2.2.1).

> Error CS0006 Metadata file  'C:\Users\olof\Source\Repos\Learning\ASP
>   Core\Integration
>   Tests\IntegrationTestExample1\IntegrationTestExample1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\IntegrationTestExample1.dll'
>   could not be found    Integration.Tests
>   C:\Users\olf\Source\Repos\Learning\ASP Core\Integration
>   Tests\IntegrationTestExample1\Integration.Tests\CSC   1   Active

The error appeared after I updated my Web application from ASP 2.1 to 2.2. After the update I had 2 folder in my web application´s debug folder: netcore2.1 and netcore2.2. I Removed the old one, but put it back after I got the error - but still the error remains.

I tried to rebuild and do a clean build several times on both projects but with no success.

Comment: You must make sure your web project and test project target the same version.

Comment: Both project seems to be using Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2 when I look inside the csproj file. (I uploaded image of project SDK:s here: http://prntscr.com/m6lguw )